# Alamofire- Certificate Pinning error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire, pinning

I am new to swift and Certificate Pinning.

I have created `.der` certificated like this `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.github.com:443 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > githubcom.der`
and imported into my project.

and then created SessionManager.

referred from [Alamofire Security](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security)

```
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy]  = [
            "github.com": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]

    let sessionManager = SessionManager(serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))

    sessionManager.request("https://github.com").response { response in // method defaults to `.get`
            debugPrint(response)
        }
```

Debug Output:

> Alamofire.DefaultDataResponse(request: Optional(https://github.com),
>   response: nil, data: Optional(0 bytes), error: Optional(Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://github.com/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://github.com/}), timeline: Timeline:
>   { "Request Start Time": 524040427.202, "Initial Response Time":
>   524040427.234, "Request Completed Time": 524040427.234, "Serialization Completed Time": 524040427.235, "Latency": 0.032 secs, "Request
>   Duration": 0.032 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.001 secs, "Total
>   Duration": 0.033 secs }, _metrics: nil)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: As I see. You are using the get method with the url https://github.com. However, nothing from that url to you get. Try again with a different url

Comment: Same problem with different url.

Comment: Are you sure the url has data?

Comment: Yes, I get HTML response printed in console if I try without certificate. for normal get request

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, for answer please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440070/5523205