# Swift client and root SSL certificate authentication

Tags: swift, ssl, token, alamofire, qliksense

Integrating get `token` api of `QLIK server`  with `ssl` certificate but after performing task I am getting error like this -

> "**finished with error - code: -999**"

```
// Your hostname and endpoint
let hostname = "YOUR_HOST_NAME"
let endpoint = "YOUR_ENDPOINT"
let cert = "YOUR_CERT" // e.g. for cert.der, this should just be "cert"

// Set up certificates
let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: cert, ofType: "der")
let localCertificate = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)
let certificates = [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate!)!]

// Configure the trust policy manager
let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
    certificates: certificates,
    validateCertificateChain: true,
    validateHost: true
)    
let serverTrustPolicies = [hostname: serverTrustPolicy]
let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

// Configure session manager with trust policy
afManager = SessionManager(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager
)



qlikManager.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

       print(responseObject)
    }
```

Please check it

Answer (score 3):

Create `CustomServerTrustPolicyManager.swift` and use below code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class CustomServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {

    override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
        // Check if we have a policy already defined, otherwise just kill the connection
        if let policy = super.serverTrustPolicy(forHost: host) {
            return policy
        } else {
            return .customEvaluation({ (_, _) -> Bool in
                return false
            })
        }
    }
}
```

then create `NetworkManager.swift` and use below code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {

    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()

    let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {

        //For using Cerificates Pinning
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "host_url": .pinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]

        /*
        //For Using with Public Key
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "host_url": .pinPublicKeys(
                publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]
        */

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: CustomServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }()
}
```

After that use like following to test your connection.

```
func testSSLConnection() {
    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.manager.request("your_url_to_test").responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You have to add your certificates in your app bundle.

Comment: But in this code they are not using anywhere ? thats why m asking
Can you please help ? I am facing this issue from last months

Comment: Yes I can help you. I am just provide you piece of code other things you have to do. See you have to add your certificates in your project bundle. and change `"host_url"` from above code with your base URL. ie `"www.example.com"`

Comment: Still getting failure as a response . I have three certificate client , root ,server .
Which certificate i need to insert ?

Comment: Check this https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/ssl-pinning-revisited for more help